# Fitting two lines to a set of 2D points

Tags: algorithm, optimization, curve-fitting, computational-geometry

Given a set of 2D points (black dots in the picture) I need to choose two lines to somehow represent those points. I probably need to minimize the sum of squares of [distance of `x` to the closer of two lines]^2, although if any other metric makes this easier, this is fine too.

The obvious but ineffective approach is to try min squares over all 2^n partitions. A practical approach is probably iterative improvement, maybe starting with a random partition.

Is there any research on algorithms to handle this problem?

[image: two lines]

Comment: You could do a linear regression over all points (and thus find a line dividing the upper from the lower points). Then for both lower and upper set of points, do another linear regression, respectively.

Comment: Yup, I'm just not sure how well this would work in case the lines intersect.

Comment: So it would also be possible, if the 2 lines were orthogonal to each other?

Comment: Also, clearly there cannot always be a unique best solution (e.g. if the points are totally random (white noise). Then it should still yield 2 lines?

Comment: White noise probably has a unique best solution. Cases like 1 point only or multiple points that are strictly linear are obviously not unique, as the second line doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two related concepts from the literature come to mind.

First, my intuition is that there should be a way to interpret this problem as estimating the parameters for a [mixture model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model). I haven't worked out the details, since parameter estimation typically uses [expectation--maximization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm), and I can just describe how that would work: initialize a partition into two parts, then alternately run a regression on each part and reassign points based on their distance to the new regression lines.

Second, assuming that the input is relatively clean, you should be able to get a good initial partition using [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus). For some small k, take two disjoint random samples of k points and fit lines through them, then assign every other point. For a (100 − x)% chance of success you'll want to repeat this about ln(100/x) × 2<sup>2k−1</sup> times and take the best one.

Comment: I once wrote answers like that and got down voted because all the content is actually in the links. It might be a good idea to explain briefly what the terms of the links mean, so the text becomes useful without following the links.

Comment: also, you might want to add factor analysis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis) to your list.

Comment: @BitTickler I described the concrete instantiations of these ideas, viz. "initialize a partition into two parts, then alternately run a regression on each part and reassign points based on their distance to the new regression lines" and "For some small k, take two disjoint random samples of k points and fit lines through them, then assign every other point". I don't see how factor analysis applies here.

Comment: Just because the question displays an image, it does not necessarily mean it is an image processing problem. It could also be a plot of statistical variables (with X, Y being the variables). If you look at my new comments below the question, you see, this is what I try to find out.

Comment: Thanks! Expectation-maximization led me to a paper on this topic: https://cse.sc.edu/~songwang/CourseProj/proj2005/report/guo.pdf

Answer (score 6):

I think this can be formulated as an explicit optimization problem:

```
 min sum(j, r1(j)^2 + r2(j)^2)                 (quadratic)
 subject to
     r1(j) = (y(j) - a0 - a1*x(j)) * δ(j)      (quadratic)
     r2(j) = (y(j) - b0 - b1*x(j)) * (1-δ(j))  (quadratic) 
     δ(j) ∈ {0,1}
```

We do the assignment of points to a line and the regression (minimization of the sum of the squared residuals) at the same time.

This is a **non-convex** quadratically constrained mixed-integer quadratic programming problem. Solvers that can handle this include Gurobi, Baron, Couenne, Antigone.

We can reformulate this a bit:

```
 min sum(j, r(j)^2)                      (convex quadratic)
 subject to
     r(j) = y(j) - a0 - a1*x(j) + s1(j)  (one of these will be relaxed)
     r(j) = y(j) - b0 - b1*x(j) + s2(j)  (all linear)
     -U*δ(j) <= s1(j) <= U*δ(j)
     -U*(1-δ(j)) <= s2(j) <= U*(1-δ(j))
     δ(j) ∈ {0,1}
     s1(j),s2(j) ∈ [-U,U]
     U = 1000                            (reasonable bound, constant)
```

This makes it a straight **convex MIQP** model. This will allow more solvers to be used (e.g. Cplex) and it is much easier to solve. Some other formulations are [here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2021/02/a-strange-regression-problem.html). Some of the models mentioned do not need the bounds I had to use in the above big-M formulation. It is noted these models deliver proven optimal solutions (for the non-convex models this would require a global solver; the convex models are easier and don't need this). Furthermore, instead of a least squares objective, we can also form an L1 objective. In the latter case we end up with a linear MIP model.

A small test confirms this works:

[image]

This problem has 50 points, and needed 1.25 seconds using Cplex's MIQP solver on a slow laptop. This may be a case of a statistical problem where MIP/MIQP methods have something to offer.

Answer (score 1):

In OPL CPLEX if I start with the example [curve fitting](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/modelbuilding/blob/master/curvefitting.mod) from [Model Buidling](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/model-building-oplcplex-alex-fleischer/)

Let me add a few points to the .dat first

```
n=24;
 
x = [1,2,3,4,5,0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.9, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5,
     5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.6, 7.0, 7.6, 8.5, 9.0, 10.0];
y = [10,20,30,40,50,1.0, 0.9, 0.7, 1.5, 2.0, 2.4, 3.2, 2.0, 2.7, 3.5,
     1.0, 4.0, 3.6, 2.7, 5.7, 4.6, 6.0, 6.8, 7.3];
```

then .mod with MIP and absolute value for distance

```
execute
{
  cplex.tilim=10;
}

int n=...;
range points=1..n;
float x[points]=...;
float y[points]=...;

int nbLines=2;

range lines=1..nbLines;

dvar float a[lines];
dvar float b[lines];

// distance between a point and a line
dvar float dist[points][lines];
// minimal distance to the closest line
dvar float dist2[points];

dvar float+ obj;
minimize obj; 

subject to
{
obj==sum(i in points) dist2[i];

forall(i in points,j in lines) dist[i][j]==abs(b[j]*x[i]+a[j]-y[i]);

forall(i in points) dist2[i]==min(l in lines ) dist[i][l];

}

// which line for each point ?
int whichline[p in points]=first({l | l in lines : dist2[p]==dist[p][l]});

execute
{

writeln("b = ",b);
writeln("a = ",a);
writeln("which line = ",whichline);
}
```

gives

```
b =  [0.6375 10]
a =  [0.58125 0]
which line =  [2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

With quadratic some reformulation

```
int n=...;
range points=1..n;
float x[points]=...;
float y[points]=...;

int nbLines=2;

range lines=1..nbLines;

dvar float a[lines];
dvar float b[lines];

dvar float distance[points][lines];
dvar boolean which[points]; // 1 means 1, 0 means 2

minimize sum(i in points,j in lines) distance[i][j]^2; 

subject to
{
forall(i in points,j in 0..1) (which[i]==j) => (distance[i][2-j]==b[2-j]*x[i]+a[2-j]-y[i]);

}



execute
{

writeln("b = ",b);
writeln("a = ",a);
writeln("which = ",which);
}
```

gives

```
b =  [0.61077 10]
a =  [0.42613 0]
which =  [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

[image]